# import statements in webpack 5 seem to wrap everything in module.exports = ""

Tags: webpack, webpacker

I recently upgraded from webpack 4 to webpack 5 along with rails webpacker 6.0.0.rc5 and am finding that before, doing something like:

```
import template from 'template.html'
```

the template variable would be `'<html></html>'`

but now after this upgrade, it is:

`'module.exports = "<html></html>"'`

How can I tell webpack to import the text and not wrap it in a module.export?

**UPDATE**

I upgraded html-loader to `3.0.1`, and now my template variable becomes the string:

```
'// Module
var code = "{{ <html></html> }} ";
// Exports
export default code;'
```

Comment: Did you find a fix?